Spring RestTemplate's 401 Response redacted (contain's [no body]) even though it has a body
Background: As a part of an API request cycle, let say, for OTP verification, we make a call to an external API (xxxx.com), that returns a 401 if the OTP is invalid, along with a JSON Response.
We use the Spring's RestTemplate, to make external calls to xxxx.com and we want to capture the 401s response as a Java Object but we Fail to do so. We see that the response is redacted.
The RestTemplate we use is from the JAR org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.5
The line that makes calls:
this.restTemplate.exchange("https://xxxx.com", HttpMethod.PUT, entity, responseType);

How we capture non-2XXs:
catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    if (successfulHttpStatuses.contains(e.getStatusCode())) {
        return e.getResponseBodyAs(responseType);
    } else {
        log.error("{} returned a {} status - {}", clientName, e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

Our Client works perfectly for 2XXs, just that during 401s, we get the log,
XXXClient returned a 401 status - [no body]

where as we expect the response to Have a body.
Please see this: Image Showing the request, via Postman, returning a response on 401
Also the external xxxx.com we mentioned uses a Bearer Authentication, and throws 401s as well for an invalid JWT.
Response headers don't contain "WWW-Authenticate", we assume the JWT we used is a valid JWT
So, I believe this is a deliberate design decision, to mask 401 responses for security reasons. Is there a work around for this situation?

Can you provide more details about how you set the bearer token in the request header?

This does not seem to be an issue with your loggin code but more with the response. Looking into the code here org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler#getErrorMessage you can see that the [ no body ] is returned when the response body is empty.

I looked deeper into the 401 [no body] issue,
I saw that Spring's Default RestTemplate implementation initializes its constructor  by using org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory, which is based on the JDK's default (java.net) implementation that throws a java.net.HttpRetryException from here.
See java.net.HttpURLConnection#HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.
So, the method org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler#getResponseBody via spring, ignores all exceptions and thus returns an empty byte array even though we have a response body.
As a fix, I had to use Apache's HttpClient Implementation by using org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory  instead, by doing this
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

This affects all streaming mode operations like POST, PUT where we dont generally get the content-length in the reponse header.
References:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/40359

As already mentioned in my comment this seems to be an issues with the response really being empty.
I put together two test to prove my point.
@Test
public void unauthorizedRequestWithBodyTest() {

    this.server
            .expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo("/unauthorized"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.PUT))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(
                    " { \"message\" : \"Something is broken\", \"status\": \"401\" } "));

    try {
        restTemplate.exchange("unauthorized", HttpMethod.PUT, null, String.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println("Response with body content:");
        System.out.printf("%s returned a %s status - %s\n\n", "clientName", e.getStatusCode(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
}

@Test
public void unauthorizedRequestWithoutBodyTest() {

    this.server
            .expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo("/unauthorized"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.PUT))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

    try {
        restTemplate.exchange("unauthorized", HttpMethod.PUT, null, String.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println("Response without body content:");
        System.out.printf("%s returned a %s status - %s\n", "clientName", e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
        System.out.printf("%s returned a %s status - %s\n\n", "clientName", e.getStatusCode(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
}

The output is the following:
Response with body content:
clientName returned a 401 UNAUTHORIZED status -  { "message" : "Something is broken", "status": "401" } 

Response without body content:
clientName returned a 401 UNAUTHORIZED status - 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
clientName returned a 401 UNAUTHORIZED status - 

From the implementation you can see that the getErrorMessage() method is returning the [no body] text when the responseBody is empty
if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(responseBody)) {
    return preface + "[no body]";
}

org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler#getErrorMessage

thanks for this deep dive, and pointing out about the DefaultResponseErrorHandler,  I tried testing on similar notes. Could you give me info about why this gave a response if I replicated the same request with postman (Pictures in the Question above)

Also @LostKatana I tried conducting the same scenario, while deploying two applications locally. App A had an endpoint similar to unauthorizedRequestWithBodyTest() App B was the one looging the response. In this case, Interestingly, I received a [No Body]

About your first comment with reference to the screenshot I cannot say for sure but possibly postman has another implementation and thus shows the body. About your second comment I'm not sure if I got that correct.
